# Как отрисовать линии на изображении?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такой скрипт(рисует треугольник по заданным координатам и вставляет его в изображение) -

```
    int[] xPoints = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(AX), Convert.ToInt32(BX), Convert.ToInt32(CX) };      
    int[] yPoints = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(AY), Convert.ToInt32(BY), Convert.ToInt32(CY) };

    int xMin = 0;
    int yMin = 0;
    if(xPoints.Min() < 0)
    {
        xMin = xPoints.Min();
    }
    if(yPoints.Min() < 0)
    {
        yMin = yPoints.Min();
    }

    int height = (yPoints.Max() + (-yMin)) * 100;
    int width = (xPoints.Max() + (-xMin)) * 100;//задаю границы и увеличиваю размеры изображения(что бы не было 6x3 пикселя)

    Image myImage = new Image();

    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
    drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 1), new Point(CX, CY  ), new Point(BX  , BY  ));
    drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(CX, CY  ), new Point(AX  , AY  ));
    drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), new Point(AX * 300, AY * 300), new Point(BX * 300, BY * 300));


    drawingContext.Close();

    RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 100, 100, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
    myImage.Source = bmp;

    MainCanvas.Children.Add(myImage);

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("Sample.png", FileMode.Create))
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
```

Рисую линии и вот, что получается - 
[image: недотреугольник]

Почему так получается? На что нужно умножать x, y(при создании Point), чтобы треугольник вписывался ровно в свои границы? И это было универсально, то-есть, если поменяю значения координат, все также будет работать нормально. Еще почему-то линия CB не рисуется. Подозреваю, что из-за того, что она находится на границе изображения. Если я сделаю запредельный размер кисти(2000), то эта линия займет все изображение, а если меньше, то она не рисуется вообще.

Comment: Уверен, отладка решит вашу проблему

Comment: зачем вообщем умножать координаты на 300? откуда взялось это число?

Comment: @yolosora нужно, чтобы подвинуть линии. Вот, что будет, если без 300 - https://imgur.com/a/6KeZTI7

Comment: @xomem черный квадрат?:D

Comment: @yolosora нет. В левом верхнем углу можешь заметить начало треугольника